# laravel/blade cycle in template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I need your help. Here is my template file. How can I make to work that template? Main problem is that I don't know how to change div class values. Now I can make working only `<div class="thumb-left">` but I also need `<div class="thumb-middle">` and `<div class="thumb-right">`.

Thank you.

```
   @extends('_layouts.main')

    @section('content')


    <div id="content-section">
    @foreach ($uploads as $upload)
        <div class="thumb-left">
            <img alt="{{ $upload->image_title }}" title="{{ $upload->image_title }}" src="/files/images/{{ $upload->imagefile }}" height="250" width="300">
            <div class="thumb-info">
                <a href="#">{{ $upload->image_title }}</a>
                <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
        <div class="thumb-middle">
            <a href="#"><img alt="sunset" title="Sunset HDR" src="img/thumb.jpg" height="250" width="300"></a>
            <div class="thumb-info">
                <a href="#">{{ $upload->image_title }}</a>
                <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="thumb-right">
            <a href="#"><img alt="sunset" title="Sunset HDR" src="img/thumb.jpg"></a>
            <div class="thumb-info">
                <a href="#">City Sunset HDR</a>
                <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>


    @stop
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
@foreach ($uploads as $upload)
    <div class="thumb-{{ array('left', 'middle', 'right')[($loop->iteration-1)%3] }}">
        <img alt="{{ $upload->image_title }}" title="{{ $upload->image_title }}" src="/files/images/{{ $upload->imagefile }}" height="250" width="300">
        <div class="thumb-info">
            <a href="#">{{ $upload->image_title }}</a>
            <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

The `$loop` variable is a build in blades variable - check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade):

> When looping, a $loop variable will be available inside of your loop.
>   This variable provides access to some useful bits of information such
>   as the current loop index and whether this is the first or last
>   iteration through the loop. For instance: `$loop->iteration` - the current loop
>   iteration (it starts at 1).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change your `foreach` to also use a key, so you can know at which `index` in your array you are:

```
<div id="content-section">
@foreach ($uploads as $index => $upload)
    <div class="thumb-left">
        <img alt="{{ $upload->image_title }}" title="{{ $upload->image_title }}" src="/files/images/{{ $upload->imagefile }}" height="250" width="300">
        <div class="thumb-info">
            <a href="#">{{ $upload->image_title }}</a>
            <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Now, if I understand properly, what you're looking for is to switch from `thumb-left`, to `thumb-middle` and then finally `thumb-right`, and then loop again. You could use `modulo` to assign your class name based on the current index.  This is untested code but you could probably use something along the lines of:

```
<div id="content-section">
{{ $classnames = array("thumb-left", "thumb-middle", "thumb-right"); }}
@foreach ($uploads as $index => $upload)
    <div class="{{ $classnames[$index % count($classnames)] }}">
        <img alt="{{ $upload->image_title }}" title="{{ $upload->image_title }}" src="/files/images/{{ $upload->imagefile }}" height="250" width="300">
        <div class="thumb-info">
            <a href="#">{{ $upload->image_title }}</a>
            <a class="cat" href="#">PHOTOS</a>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: {{ $classnames = array("thumb-left", "thumb-middle", "thumb-right"); }} will echo $classnames

Comment: @carlosvini in which case, simply passing classnames to the view should do the trick

Comment: You can also do <?php $classnames = array(...); ?>, but i don't know if it's a good practice to mix php and blade, you could create your own blade tag like: \@set($classnames, array(...)), and an if would work too: \@if ($classnames = array(...)) .... \@endif